# GCM using google play service library and Rest Webservice

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging

How to use GCM using google play service as library since google cloud messaging is deprecated
and Rest Web Srevice?I have Rest webservice.I have searched on net but most example are in php and examples having Rest webservice is using google cloud messsaging and not google play service.Can any one Post source code or Example ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since when is [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) deprecated?

Comment: Does any one have Source code using GCM both client and Rest Webservice as third party server?please help!!!

Comment: This is not a "give me the code" site...

Comment: I have searched but i cant find any link that have done back end using Rest Webservice.All the links have done it in php.

Comment: So? Understand the PHP code and program the same functionality in java... where is the problem? Right: You want already working, ready to be used, not done by yourself code... Pay someone if you need it or implement it by yourself. Two possibilities, your choice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecated library is the client library, `gcm.jar` (the one with the GCMRegistrar class). That library was indeed replaced by the `google-play-services` library.

However, the gcm server library (`gcm-server.jar`) wasn't deprecated, and you can still use it to send HTTP requests to the GCM server in Java. You can find links to Demo code [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html).

Comment: do you have demo source code using Rest webservice